# Myth/Customs related to shaving & hairwash

Tags: tradition, customs

I have heard a lot of myth related to shaving beard and moustache.

> 1. Those whose father is alive should **NOT** shave.
> 2. We should not Shave on Thursday(because wealth might go away) and Saturday.
> 3. There are people who think that cutting hair on Saturdays help cut down Saade Sati of Shani Dev.
> 4. It is also believed that one should not wash their hair or clothes on a Thursday.
> 5. There is also a myth for not cutting hair or shaving on Tuesday

There are many stories about shaving and hair wash in Hinduism which are practiced by many religious people.

Being a Senior technocrat, We are expected to be clean shaved. Shall I go without taking care of  specific **DAYS** or is there any combination of allowed days which let us manage with these customs as well as our daily life style.

Please share some other myths related to this.

Comment: each day of the week is dedicated to some god in hinduism.....curious if someone could answer this

Comment: Every organ in our body, is there for a reason. But Science has no explanation for our Hairs. Biology doesn't completely understands everything i.e "BIO". And what we don't understand, is a more of a Mystery, than a Myth. Moreover, Science is rooted in an "unacknowledged" idea that phenomenas are like Sets, which have specific boundaries separating each other entirely. It CAN NOT talk about the "Universal Set". But Hinduism, on the other hand, sits on the idea of the Fractal view for the Entirety. So it's "perspectives" can be understood only with the LOST knowledge of Meta-physics in mind.

Comment: In your comment line `But Science has no explanation for our Hairs`. is wrong hairs are there becoz of severeal reasons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shaving / Haircut / Nailcut - what days are allowed / prohibited?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/shaving-haircut-nailcut-what-days-are-allowed-prohibited)

Comment: As mentioned above, the haircut days are already in answer. Similarly there is an answer on clean head shave when father's alive: irrespective of parents status, one must not clean shave.

Answer (score 8):

> Those whose father is alive should NOT shave.

There isn't anything like this. You are not allowed to have a clean shave (shaving moustache) if your elder brother is alive.  Only brahmins are not allowed to have a clean head, as they need shikha. others can have clean head without any issue.

> We should not Shave on Thursday(because wealth might go away) and Saturday.

Its belief that you should not do activities like washing clothes, shaving, using soaps etc on days when someone in your family fasts on that day or has fasted previously. Thursday is common in this context as usually people fast on this day.
Basically as a sacrifice.

> There are people who think that cutting hair on Saturdays help cut down Saade Sati of Shani Dev.

No, it doesn't. Actually people don't cut hair on saturdays. Neither do people purchase new things on saturday.

> It is also believed that one should not wash their hair or clothes on a Thursday.

considered a sacrifice

> There is also a myth for not cutting hair or shaving on Tuesday

Same because its considered a sacrifice.

Moreover anyone calling practices in our religion as myth or superstition is due to the western class of thinking. They made us look like idiots so that we underestimate ourselves.

Please note that its scientifically well proven by our archaeologist's & scientist's that we are much older civilizations than them, our thought processes and everything is much more advanced than them and hence our beliefs.

Traditions which have been here since millions of years (yes, Ramayana happened 1.7 million yr ago) cannot be defied by some western retards, and we must follow rules and regulations our forefathers have set for us, to have a healthy and prosperous life.

Comment: when you say scientifically proven, what exactly do you mean? because usually it means there is a derivation or a proof exists or shown somewhere. If so, where is it?  I am asking to seek answer, not to defy beliefs.

Comment: Please provide scriptural references to this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Saturn governs the hair of the body and hence sacrifice of hair on a Saturday is like minimizing the effects of Saturn whether good or bad. Thursday belongs to Jupiter, the planet of EXPANSION and GROWTH.One should not shave or cut hair on this day because it may diminish one's progress. This is especially true if in the native's birth chart Jupiter is afflicted. Saturn holds back hence if Saturn (hair) is cut, it will be less effective in holding back Jupiter. Tuesday is a day for Mars, a cruel planet..cutting the holding back power of Saturn ( cutting hair/shaving) would give a free reign to Mars.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE!  You should cite sources.