# Is it mandatory to shave beard also along with head

Tags: rituals, tradition, death, customs

After someone's demise, I know family member's go through a ritual where they shave off their head but I heard a new thing from my house Pandit Ji, he said now it is mandatory to shave beard also, however you can keep a little mustache.
I had to do it but still I have a doubt that head I know but why beard?
Can anyone tell me the reason behind shaving beard?

Comment: Listen to what Panditji has to say at such a time.

Comment: See the following answer. While participating in any ritual, whether for deities or for deceased ancestors, shaving the head and beard is recommended. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/29689

Comment: @Rickross This answer talks about Brahmins but what about others? Like I am vaishya so it is recommended for all?

Comment: Yes it is applicable to everyone. According to Hinduism, sins are stored in hairs. So less hair the more pure the body is. @RahulBansal Also, in such cases, the local traditions, the family traditions are to be followed. So, we have to follow what our family Purohit is saying.

Comment: "Listen to what Panditji has to say at such a time." He'll probably say that you won't have to do it if you pay him your life savings...

Comment: and, thus Fear the Beard is introduced ay?