# Are they referencing a gregorian calendar or some Hindu calendar?

Tags: calendar

I know this could sound silly but I really want to be sound and safe.

On the following topic:

[Shaving / Haircut / Nailcut - what days are allowed / prohibited?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/10025/shaving-haircut-nailcut-what-days-are-allowed-prohibited?newreg=2da695ee8fca4913a65bb77b38f7833e)

They are referring to an Hindu calendar or other?

Comment: You can comment and ask under the question or answer given that you have enough reputation to comment. Sunday, Monday also exist in Hindu calendar also.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma I have posted comment, thanks.

Comment: @Sarvabhouma no answer received on the other thread...

Answer (score 1):

The 7 days of the week (vara) are an ancient concept in Sanatan Dharma (aka Hinduism). They are mentioned in Jyotisha which is one of the 6 veda-angas.

The Gregorian calendar copies this, so they're the same.

Sunday - Bhanu-vasara (Bhanu = sun)
Monday - Soma-vasara (Soma = moon)

Similarly, Mars, Mercury, Jupiter, Venus, Saturn, in that order.

These are 7 of the nava-gruhas (9 positions), aka the 7 planets.

http://astrology.aryabhatt.com/astrology_panchang.asp

Comment: No. The seven day week in the Gregorian calendar is derived from the Book of Genesis in the Bible / Torah, where God created the universe in six days and rested on the seventh day. It's not copied from Hinduism.

Comment: @ruben2020, the 7 days of the week, the 'gods' the refer to, and the planets they refer to, are the same. e.g. Friday is derived from the goddess Frigg, the Roman goddess of love Venus. Friday in Hinduism is Shukra-vasra. Shukra is presiding deity of Venus. Saturday - Saturn - Shani. The concept of Noah's ark and the flood is copied from Manu & Matsya avatar. There are many more, almost all religious concepts in all religions have their birth in Hinduism, they are Hinduism Diluted 2.0, 3.0 etc.

Comment: I did some online reading. The planetary week of seven days was definitely invented by the West. Nobody is sure exactly who invented it - it could be the Sumerians, Babylonians, Jews or Greeks - most probably it was invented by the Babylonians. The Greeks received this from the Babylonians in 4th century BCE, but invented planetary hours in 2nd century BCE. Later, India received Hellenistic astrology from the Greeks during the Gupta period, which is on or after 3rd century CE. Also, apparently astrology was invented by the Babylonians.

Comment: Also see the wikipedia article [Yavanajātaka](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yavanajataka).

Comment: @ruben2020, nope. Jyotisha (astrology) is one of the 6 veda-angas. Vedas are eternal. Even if you want to put a date on it, Vyasa divided vedas into 4 categories at beginning of Kali Yug which is 3102 BC. All other civilizations are merely offshoots.